# Manga where the female main character gains magical power after leaving her home country

Tags: story-identification, manga

I think I read this in 2022. It was definitely after 2020. I believe it was fairly recent at the time. It is a Japanese black & white manga. The demographic is either Shoujo or Josei. I don't recall any characters names or appearances.

The main character is a noble or royalty of some sort, but is maligned by her family and possibly society due to a lack of magic power. For some reason I can't precisely recall, she ends up leaving her house and going to another country. I assume for one of these reasons,

1. She decided to run away because she was sick of her family's treatment
2. She was kicked out for her lack of magic power
3. She was married off to a noble from another country in a purely political marriage.

I can't remember for certain which it is. If she was a runaway, I *think* she cuts her hair to be less obvious. Regardless, she leaves the country and meets a man, the male lead of the story, and they start traveling together. If he isn't already her husband, I think he was a noble pretending to be an adventurer. If so, he wasn't alone and had other male companions.

Some circumstances lead them to a spring, lake, fountain, or some other body of water. After entering or praying at the water, she suddenly awakens to her full magical power. The reasoning behind this is that there's a baptism-like ceremony for awakening magic powers, and she is from this other country. During her ceremony she was baptized at the wrong "incompatible" country, and this is why she always seemed to have a severe lack of magic power. I think she was either adopted and never informed of this, or she was actually the child of a mistress from this other country.

I think that was the last chapter that I read and don't know anything that happened afterwards. This was probably around chapter 5 or 6. Fairly early in the story, but definitely not in the first chapter. The exile would be in the first chapter.

I don't remember any isekai or reincarnation elements, but I can't rule them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *[Formerly, the Fallen Daughter of the Duke](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/formerly-the-fallen-daughter-of-the-duke)*.

> Betrothed to Prince Asbert of the great kingdom of Noston, Claire is shocked when the engagement is suddenly annulled. More than that, the new consort to the throne is none other than her sister, Charlotte! As the daughter of the now disgraced duke and scorned as a villainess, **Claire leaves everything she knows and sets out on a journey to find her true self**. But wait, isn't that's the plot of the game "Upstart ♡ ETERNAL LOVE" on its hardest difficult setting...?

The story opens with her engagement being cancelled in favor of her half-sister, an illegitimate child that was adopted into the family. She leaves the household after cutting her hair.

She wasn't quite being abused - there was the scene with her weak baptismal, while her sister received the second best rank. This sours everyone's opinion of her, but it doesn't appear to turn into actual abuse. With the exception of her sister lying and telling people the protagonist abuses her, but she learned of this after deciding to leave.

While in the carriage she falls asleep and dreams of another life in the modern world and learns that her world is the world of an otome game. This isn't memories of a past life; she appears to be living both lives simultaneously.

She does meet a man acting as an adventurer, with escorts, and later learns that he's the prince, thanks to her otherworldly dreams.

The baptismal scene is in chapter 3. They visit the site of a former church. There's no intention to do a re-baptism or anything, it's just a convenient spring. The background is that the baptism needs to be done in the spring of her mother's birthplace. The protagonist did not know that her mother was actually from another country, and only discovered this for certain when reading the game manual in her other life.

[image: Baptism backstory]     [image: After the new baptism]

This is also how she discovers that the man she's been traveling with is a prince in disguise.